# Modernising a 90s Warhammer 40K Army

Tags: warhammer-40k

I collected and gamed with a Blood Angel and Dark Angel army during the mid to late 90s.  I have (I think) the second edition that came in a box set of basic Space Marines and Orks, and also have the Dark Millenium expansion.  I've been wondering recently what I would need to get to bring myself up to date with the current (7th) edition/rules.  If I were to get the newer models/squads etc, I would need at least the codex.  However presumably that itself would mean I need the updated rule book.  What about the likes of the wargear cards, warp cards, vehicle data cards etc?  Would the wide range of templates (flamer, blast radius etc) still be applicable?

Also, whilst looking over some of my items I found a few old blister packs with a price on, so had a quick compare of prices.  However, one of the blister packs was Brother Bethor - he no longer seems to be available.  Presumably he'd be missing from a modern Codex and associated rules/points cost may no longer be valid.  I'm concerned this might also apply to other models in my army - how would this be resolved properly?

Comment: Aww, Heavy Flamer template :( I miss that thing.

Comment: Not needed, but certainly useful, would be Battlescribe. This could give you an idea of how many points of models you have, and to a lesser extent, what you will need/want to buy.

Comment: @aslum Thanks, will take a look!  Since asking this I've now started building up a Necron force :)  Kinda wishing I'd still been collecting in the intermediary years - could have had quite a display by now!

Comment: It's especially useful once you have a large army and lots of options to choose from. The pro version is IMO well worth it, as you can save favorite units (I almost always take the same Deamon Princess, and it's really nice to be able to add her with a single click, for example.) That said the free version is still a huge time saver on the list construction front.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need the [core rule book](http://www.games-workshop.com/en-GB/Warhammer-40-000-EN-A) and codex to start.  Both the [Dark Angels](http://www.games-workshop.com/en-GB/Codex-Dark-Angels-EN) and [Blood Angels](http://www.games-workshop.com/en-GB/Codex-Blood-Angels-EN) codexes are separate books now.  There are [scenario cards](http://www.games-workshop.com/en-GB/Warhammer-40-000-Tactical-Objectives) and [psychic cards](http://www.games-workshop.com/en-GB/Warhammer-40-000-Psychic-Powers) for the current edition, but they are optional.  The game currently uses the 3" and 5" templates along with the teardrop flamer.  Those, a measuring device, a scatter die, and copious d6s is all that is required for play outside of minis and terrain.

The special characters available have changed much since 2nd edition.  The big ones like Dante, Mephiston, Ezekiel, and such are still around.  Generally if a character has gone away, there is usually a generic HQ options that you can still use the model for, such as a Blood Angel Sanguinary Priest and in the case of Bethor Dark Angels chapter standard bearer.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.  Not looked at it for years - was thinking of starting a Tyranid army, but really liking the look of the Necrons as well now!  Best start saving up...

Answer (score 0):

Really, the only thing you would have to invest in is the codex, rulebook and new templates. All of your army would still be completely valid. The Uniques can always be substituted for one of the generic HQs, and would still be permitted in tournaments (The uniques cost more than the generics, so GW makes more money, and let you play). Unless you're really set on running BA and DA, a generic SM codex might be better until you get to grips with the new rules of alliances and so forth. You would have to do very little work configuring a BA DA army into a generic SM army, and these days the armies are so similar anyway that it wouldn't be too much of a loss, especially if you are going to switch back again (get the digital codex to begin with, it's cheaper). While I run BAs myself, I still find having an SM codex really useful, so it would not be a wasted investment anyway. Good to see you're re-entering the 41st millennium!